# CSS empty selector insane logic

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        tbody:empty::after { content: 'empty'; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>text </tbody> <!-- output: "text " (newline) "empty" -->
<!--    <tbody>text</tbody>  <!-- output: "text"  (newline) "empty" -->
<!--    <tbody></tbody>      <!-- output: "empty" -->
<!--    <tbody> </tbody>     <!-- output: "" -->
<!--    <tbody><p></tbody>   <!-- output: "empty" -->
<!--    <tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody> <!-- output: "" -->
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not intuitive at all.

"text " tests as empty
"text"  tests as empty
""      tests as empty
" "     tests as NOT empty
"< tr>< td>< /td>< /tr>"     tests as NOT empty
"< p>"   tests as empty

So basically anything other than all whitespace (or table tags) tests as empty.
How backwards is that?
I would expect "" and " " to test as empty.  Or anything other than valid tags for tbody to test as empty.
But for text to test as empty while whitespace tests as NOT empty, is insane.
Applies to at least IE11 and Chrome.  Probably others browsers too.

Here's the question.  How can a test be done for all whitespace tbody and inject content in such case?

Comment: Well, putting anything except a tr in a tbody is an error, so this is just the browser's error handling at work. I wouldn't be surprised if different browsers have different outcomes. If you start out with valid html by dispensing with the tables and using divs or something, the result is exactly as you expect.

Comment: I agree, but by that logic an all whitespace tbody should also be considered empty, and only a tbody containing a tr should be considered NOT empty.

Comment: Maybe. But in the case of a space, the behaviour is identical to that of a div: a truly empty div says "empty", while a div with one space does not. So at least it's consistent! Also, on my machine `<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>` is not empty, which is good. Are you saying your findings are different?

Comment: By the way, to return to the error handling: if you look at the table with the inspector in your browser, you'll see that it puts the "text" text node _before_ the table in the DOM tree, while leaving the tbody itself empty. The result, although it looks counterintuitive at face value, is again consistent.